# Why is there a difference in sizing between interface builder and the simulator?

Tags: xcode4, interface-builder, ios-simulator

I am working in xcode4 and I am really confused by why there is a difference in sizing between the interface builder and the simulator, see the difference below.

Interface builder:

[image: Interface Builder]

Simulator:

[image]

Comment: Let me guess... iPhone 5 in IB, and iPhone 4 in the simulator? Ever heard of auto-layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the storyboard, click on the following button:

[image]

This sets the size of the elements of the storyboard for bigger screens.